# trouble with url not stored in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

During page loads I append certain parts to my URL like http://myproject.com/Page1.aspx**/id=219** to help me with storing some info between postbacks, however I don't want to keep this URL in the database. 
So in case someone copies it, and loads it for the first time in their browser, it should be rerouted to http://myproject.com/Page1.aspx

Can this be done and how? Is it good practice?

More context: the id is dependent on temporarily generated controls

Are there better ways? My current http://myproject.com/Page1.aspx**/id=219** loads same content as http://myproject.com/Page1.aspx if loaded suddenly with no context

On the contrary loading http://myproject.com/Page1.aspx** first and interacting with the page will lead to http://myproject.com/Page1.aspx**/id=219** properly loaded

Comment: authentication and authorization of your application

Comment: why don't you store the 'id=219' in HTML5's local storage or in a cookie? Why do you need to append it to the url?

Comment: You probably need to provide us with more details for us to help.  What does the "id" parameter represent?  Is it the id of the current user?  Information about the state of the page?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a cookie, session variable, or browser localstorage to store this data and not send it through the url at all?

Comment: That's more of a cross-question to OP. Not a solid answer I would say.